# Handle optional parameters in QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL with SpringData.
I have Table say, `Employee` and I have created entity class say, `EmployeeEntity`
I have written following *service* method

```
public EmployeeEntity getEmployees(String firstName, String lastName)
{
    QEmployeeEntity employee = QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity;
    BooleanExpression query = null;
    if(firstName != null)
    {
        query = employee.firstName.eq(firstName);
    }
    if(lastName != null)
    {
        query = query.and(employee.lastName.eq(lastName)); // NPException if firstName is null as query will be NULL
    }
    return empployeeDAO.findAll(query);
}
```

As in above I commented the `NPException`. How to use *QueryDSL* for optional Parameters in *QueryDSL* using Spring Data?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`BooleanBuilder` can be used as a dynamic builder for boolean expressions:

```
public EmployeeEntity getEmployees(String firstName, String lastName) {
    QEmployeeEntity employee = QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity;
    BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
    if (firstName != null) {
        where.and(employee.firstName.eq(firstName));
    }
    if (lastName != null) {
        where.and(employee.lastName.eq(lastName));
    }
    return empployeeDAO.findAll(where);
}
```

Comment: but if we have joins ? can you help me out there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792778/dynamic-search-by-criteria

Answer (score 10):

BooleanBuilder is good. You can also wrap it and add "optional" methods in order to avoid the if conditions:

For example, for "and" you can write: (Java 8 lambdas are used)

```
public class WhereClauseBuilder implements Predicate, Cloneable
{
    private BooleanBuilder delegate;

    public WhereClauseBuilder()
    {
        this.delegate = new BooleanBuilder();
    }

    public WhereClauseBuilder(Predicate pPredicate)
    {
        this.delegate = new BooleanBuilder(pPredicate);
    }

    public WhereClauseBuilder and(Predicate right)
    {
        return new WhereClauseBuilder(delegate.and(right));
    }

    public <V> WhereClauseBuilder optionalAnd(@Nullable V pValue, LazyBooleanExpression pBooleanExpression)
    {
        return applyIfNotNull(pValue, this::and, pBooleanExpression);
    }

    private <V> WhereClauseBuilder applyIfNotNull(@Nullable V pValue, Function<Predicate, WhereClauseBuilder> pFunction, LazyBooleanExpression pBooleanExpression)
    {
        if (pValue != null)
        {
            return new WhereClauseBuilder(pFunction.apply(pBooleanExpression.get()));
        }

        return this;
    }
   }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface LazyBooleanExpression
    {
        BooleanExpression get();
    }
```

And then the usage would be much cleaner:

```
public EmployeeEntity getEmployees(String firstName, String lastName) {
    QEmployeeEntity employee = QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity;

    return empployeeDAO.findAll
    (
       new WhereClauseBuilder()
           .optionalAnd(firstName, () -> employee.firstName.eq(firstName))
           .optionalAnd(lastName, () -> employee.lastName.eq(lastName))
    );
}
```

It is possible also to use jdk's Optional class

Answer (score 3):

This is Java 101 actually: check for `null` and initialize the query instead of concatenating predicates. So a helper method like this could do the trick:

```
private BooleanExpression createOrAnd(BooleanExpression left, BooleanExpression right) {
  return left == null ? right : left.and(right);
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
BooleanExpression query = null;

if (firstName != null) {
  query = createOrAnd(query, employee.firstName.eq(firstName));
}

if (lastName != null) {
  query = createOrAnd(query, employee.lastName.eq(lastName));
}

…
```

Note, that I use `createOrAnd(…)` even in the first clause simply for consistency and to not have to adapt that code in case you decide to add a new clause even before the one for `firstName`.

Answer (score 2):

if you check the QueryDSL implementation of `null`:

```
public BooleanExpression and(@Nullable Predicate right) {
    right = (Predicate) ExpressionUtils.extract(right);
    if (right != null) {
        return BooleanOperation.create(Ops.AND, mixin, right);
    } else {
        return this;
    }
}
```

which is supposedly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem and here comes another version of [Timo Westkämper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252552/timo-westk%c3%a4mper)
's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896303/330457) using the `Optional`.

```java
default Optional<Correlation> findOne(
        @Nonnull final String value, @Nullable final String environment,
        @Nullable final String application, @Nullable final String service) {
    final QSome Some = QSome.some;
    final BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    ofNullable(service).map(some.service::eq).map(builder::and);
    ofNullable(application).map(some.application::eq).map(builder::and);
    ofNullable(environment).map(some.environment::eq).map(builder::and);
    builder.and(some.value.eq(value));
    return findOne(builder);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me out! I like how the code is written!

Answer (score 1):

For any one wants to build predicate based on dynamic request parameters map instead of specific ones can use the following simple format,

```
public List<User> searchUser(Map<String, Optional<String>> requestParams ){
        QUser qUser = Quser.qUser;
    
        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
        requestParams.forEach( (String key, String value) -> {
            if(!value.isEmpty()) {
                StringPath column = Expressions.stringPath(qUser, key);
               builder.and(column.eq(value));
            }
        });
  }
```

And here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> searchUser(
            @RequestParam() Map<String, Optional<String>> requestParams) {

        List<User> userList = userService.searchUser(requestParams);
        
         if(userList!=null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userList, HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<>(userList, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on what you need i would do this

```
public List<EmployeeEntity> getEmployees(Optional<String> firstName, Optional<String> lastName)
{
    BooleanExpression queryPredicate =  QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity.firstName.containsIgnoreCase(firstName.orElse("")).and(QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity.lastName.containsIgnoreCase(lastName.orElse(""))); 
    return empployeeDAO.findAll(queryPredicate);
}
```

First of all you should return a `List` of `EmployeeEntity`. Second, its better to use optional than checking if its `null`, and you may pass Java 8's `Optional` values obtained from optional `RequestParam` ones like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView queryEmployee(@RequestParam(value = "firstName", required = false) Optional<String> firstName, @RequestParam(value = "lastName", required = false) Optional<String> lastName) 
{
       List<EmployeeEntity> result =  getEmployees(firstName, lastName);    
            ....
}
```

And a very important thing is to use the `containsIgnoreCase` function in the predicate: its better than a typical `like` cause its case insensitive.

In my opinion you should use some approach like this:

```
@Controller
class UserController {

  @Autowired UserRepository repository;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  String index(Model model, @QuerydslPredicate(root = User.class) Predicate predicate,    
          Pageable pageable, @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters) {

    model.addAttribute("users", repository.findAll(predicate, pageable));

    return "index";
  }
}
```

look it at [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way to deal with optional parameters, I use it in my project :

```
    public List<ResultEntity> findByOptionalsParams(String param1, Integer param2) {
    QResultEntity qResultEntity = QResultEntity.resultEntity;
    final JPQLQuery<ResultEntity> query = from(qResultEntity);
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(param1)) {
      query.where(qResultEntity.field1.like(Expressions.asString("%").concat(param1).concat("%")));
    }
    if (param2 != null) {
      query.where(qResultEntity.field2.eq(param2));
    }
    return query.fetch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using `Optional` without `BooleanBuilder` although the resulting query might be a bit verbose:

```
public EmployeeEntity getEmployees(String firstName, String lastName) {
    QEmployeeEntity employee = QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity;
    BooleanExpression where = ofNullable(firstName).map(employee.firstName::eq).orElse(Expressions.TRUE)
            .and(ofNullable(lastName).map(employee.lastName::eq).orElse(Expressions.TRUE));

    return empployeeDAO.findAll(where);
}
```

Taking that idea and adding a helper function improves readability though:

```
public EmployeeEntity getEmployees(String firstName, String lastName) {
    QEmployeeEntity employee = QEmployeeEntity.employeeEntity;
    BooleanExpression where = optionalExpression(firstName, employee.firstName::eq)
            .and(optionalExpression(lastName, employee.lastName::eq));

    return empployeeDAO.findAll(where);
}

public static <T> BooleanExpression optionalExpression(T arg, Function<T, BooleanExpression> expressionFunction) {
    if (arg == null) {
        return Expressions.TRUE;
    }
    return expressionFunction.apply(arg);
}
```