# Spring Data JPA Query DSL to relax null parameter

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Similar to [Handle optional parameters in QueryDSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750528/handle-optional-parameters-in-querydsl), I need to change existing Spring Query DSL methods like  findByName(String name) 
so that the following condition is satisfied

```
name = :nameParam And (:ownerParam is null OR owner is null OR owner = :ownerParam)
```

where owner  is a new column in the existing entity/table.

Following the Table 2.3. of [Supported keywords inside method names](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

I have changed to findByName**AndOwnerOrOwnerIsNull**(String nameParam, String ownerParam)  for

```
name = :nameParam And (owner is null OR owner = :ownerParam)
```

Though I'm not sure about the precedence of  **Or**, **And** in query DSL.

Any help on this is more than welcome.

I am using

- spring-data-commons-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar
- spring-data-jpa-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar
- (i)hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.14.SP1-redhat-1.jar, (ii)
  hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar offered by JBOSS EAP 6.3